# Custom function: return value different than setValues()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a custom function in Sheets that takes the serial number of a device and returns warranty information from the manufacturer's API. If I call the function on a single serial number, I get the expected output in the adjacent cells of the spreadsheet, but when I call it on a range containing serial numbers I get a blank cell back.

I created a second test function, using `setValues()` to populate the data instead, and it works perfectly:

```
var result = GET_WARRANTY(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange("Warranty Details!H3:H9").getValues());
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange("Warranty Details!I3:L9").setValues(result)
```

For reference, here is the contents of the `result` variable (newlines added for readability). Using `typeof()` shows that all the data is seen as strings within Apps Script.

```
[[[EXTENDED], [2016-06-12], [2018-06-11], [latitude-e5450-laptop]],
[[INITIAL], [2016-08-03], [2017-11-01], [chromebook-11-3120]],
[[INITIAL], [2017-03-26], [2018-03-26], [chromebook-13-3380-laptop]],
[[INITIAL], [2016-08-03], [2017-11-01], [chromebook-11-3120]],
[[INITIAL], [2016-08-03], [2017-11-01], [chromebook-11-3120]],
[[INITIAL], [2016-08-03], [2017-11-01], [chromebook-11-3120]],
[[INITIAL], [2016-08-03], [2017-11-01], [chromebook-11-3120]]]
```

The end of my custom function is

```
//mutliple inputs
results.push([[warrantyType],[warrantyStart],[warrantyEnd],[model]]);
//single input
var results = [warrantyType,warrantyStart,warrantyEnd,model];
return results;
```

where `warrantyType`, `warrantyStart`, `warrantyEnd`, and `model` are all strings parsed out of the API JSON response.

I am not finding anything explaining the behavior of the function's `return results;` to explain why the same data doesn't behave the same way between the two processes.

Comment: @i-i Sorry, meant that in a general sense. My custom function has `return result;`. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @I'-'I could have sworn I tried that, I went through several variations of the nested arrays, but that did the trick. If you want to submit it as an answer I'll mark it correct. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change 3D array to 2D array:

Try changing from:

```
results.push([[warrantyType],[warrantyStart],[warrantyEnd],[model]]);
```

to

```
results.push([warrantyType,warrantyStart,warrantyEnd,model]);
```